# Connect Error(2002)Connection refused (Heroku)

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, xampp

I have been trying to connect to my database (I used Xampp) and made a PHP trying to link the file to the "users" database that I made. There is an issue as whenever I click the "Register" button it has an error saying "Connect Error(2002)Connection refused." Any help would be appreciated!

PHP code

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];

if (!empty($name) || !empty($username) || !empty($password) || !empty($email) || !empty($phone)) {

    $host = "localhost:80";
    $dbUsername = "root";
    $dbPassword = "";
    $dbname = "pracdata";


    //create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($host, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbname);
    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
     die('Connect Error('. mysqli_connect_errno().')'. mysqli_connect_error());
    } else {
     $SELECT = "SELECT email From users Where email = ? Limit 1";
     $INSERT = "INSERT Into users (name, username, password, email, phone) values(?, ?, ?, ?)";


     //Prepare statement
     $stmt = $conn->prepare($SELECT);
     $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
     $stmt->execute();
     $stmt->bind_result($email);
     $stmt->store_result();
     $rnum = $stmt->num_rows;

     if ($rnum==0) {
      $stmt->close();
      $stmt = $conn->prepare($INSERT);
      $stmt->bind_param("ssssii", $username, $username, $password, $email, $phone);

      $stmt->execute();
      echo "Your account has been registered!";
     } else {
      echo "This email is already linked to Preak account";
     }
     $stmt->close();
     $conn->close();
    }
} else {
 echo "All fields are required";
 die();
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi Benajmin that error means you don't have permission or connection to database try to use XMPP control panel > click on Admin of MySQL check if you can connect via that way if it is so check db name and try to connect without port number also please search forum before ask. Thank you for your contribution [Search Result][1]


  [1]: https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=Connect%20Error(2002)Connection%20refused%20site:stackoverflow.com&safe=active&client=opera&hs=Uvi&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiq_Y3Z_NPnAhWssaQKHVv4C2kQrQIoBDAAegQIBxAO&biw=1880&bih=939

Comment: I have tried to insert the port number in localhost, however the error still appears, I also tried running it as admin

Comment: can you connect from browser as http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

Comment: yes, I can start a localhost server.

Comment: Try 127.0.0.1 as host with no port

Comment: [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Q5Jn.png